# Installing an MSI in remote machine using WMIC

Tags: powershell, wix, windows-installer, remote-access, wmic

I tried to install an MSI in a remote machine through wmic command in PowerShell.

The Command i used trigger the MSI is as below

```
 wmic /node:192.xxx.xx.xx /user:"user" /password:"Password" product call install true,"","\\remoteIP\c$\Program Files\My_Location\My_Installation_File.msi"
```

But I recieve an error as mentioned below

```
Invalid format.
Hint: <paramlist> = <param> [, <paramlist>].
```

Why am i getting this error

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure how relevant it is for remote installation, but I want to add that there is now an [**Windows Installer Powershell Module**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53436779/129130).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try the same in command prompt you will get it done...