# Having issues scripting .msi custom setup

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, powershell-ise

I'm currently trying to install an .msi silently, but can't get past the custom setup part.

I've tried the code below, but it keeps popping up with the Windows Installer help guide.

```
$AppSetup = msiexec --% /i '\deploy\PostImageInstall\Logger Pro 3.msi' INSTALLDATASHARE="INSTALL" /qn /L*v %TEMP%\LoggerPro3_msilog.txt
```

The code is supposed to silently install the .msi with the custom setup option.

Comment: 1. Don't use `Start-Process`; it's not doing anything here.  2. Use `--%` after calling `msiexec` so the rest of your command is interpreted by the parent instead of powershell.  This should resolve your issues.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 1. thank you I wasn't sure if that was needed or not 2. even with the --% it still pops up with the windows installer guide.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you're trying now?  If that's the case, I suspect it's an issue with the msi more than anything else.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I'm starting to wonder if it's even possible to do it with this application.

Comment: Why do you have `-FilePath` in there?  That was an argument to `Start-Process`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 my bad this is honestly my second week using powershell lol. I'll remove all arguments from the script

Comment: [Just a link, heading out the door...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53436779/129130).

Comment: `%TEMP%` is not a valid variable in that context, and you may want to try changing `INSTALLDATASHARE="INSTALL"` to `"INSTALLDATASHARE=INSTALL"`.