# How to install MSI with silent installation

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am new to power shell, I want to install .msi for this we are using below command,

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\abc.xuz\Downloads\Firefox Setup 14.0.1.msi'
```

However this is giving me an error.
Along with this it should automatically accept next button.
Please help me for the same.

Comment: According to [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/deploy-firefox-msi-installers#w_supported-msiexec-options) you should add the `/q` switch for silent install on the .msi. If you unpack the msi first and use the `.exe`, the silent switch is `-ms`. What error did you get? Please add that error in full to your question.

Comment: I tried both of below commands  -1  Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\abc.xuz\Downloads\Firefox Setup 14.0.1.msi /q' and  Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList 'C:\Users\abc.xuz\Downloads\Firefox Setup 14.0.1.msi /ms'   bot of tem gives error as prompt message Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.18362.1 

msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter]
....

Comment: Can you try `Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '"C:\Users\abc.xuz\Downloads\Firefox Setup 14.0.1.msi"', '/i', '/q'`

Comment: still getting pop up message with details like.... Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.18362.1 

msiexec /Option <Required Parameter> [Optional Parameter]

Install Options
 </package | /i> <Product.msi>
  Installs or configures a product
 /a <Product.msi>
  Administrative install - Installs a product on the network
 /j<u|m> <Product.msi> [/t <Transform List>] [/g <Language ID>]
  Advertises a product - m to all users, u to current user
 </uninstall | /x> <Product.msi | ProductCode>
  Uninstalls the product
Display Options
 /quiet
  Quiet mode, no user interaction
 /passive
  ...

Comment: Some previous answers: [Silent installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53436779/129130) (describes a Powershell module for the task and regular cmd.exe versions for silent installation). [Silent installation](https://superuser.com/a/1248364/11906) (short version - from Superuser).

Comment: tried the same, however still getting error.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this and it worked:

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/i 
"C:\Users\abc.xuz\Downloads\Firefox Setup 14.0.1.msi" /q /le 
"C:\Users\abc.xuz\Downloads\Firefox.log"'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help [Silent installation of a MSI package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package)

If you planning to automate the installtion then why don't you consider using chocolatey. Its a far better way than writting your own custom script.

It also provides option for installation/uninstall, specific version of package etc.

Steps to use chocolatey

1. You need to [Install chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation) on your machine first
2. Use `choco install firefox` to install it. Find more details [here](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Firefox)

Comment: Actually I can not use any other. Please help me with powershell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package

Comment: what should be value of PROPERTY1 and PROPERTY2, plz help me

Answer (score 0):

With below instruction, you can download MSI installer and print its version

git-bash command

```
curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/a/a/c/aacb9da7-b103-4bec-99ab-cfaf28b0ba78/x64/DacFramework.msi
```

power-shell command

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/i "D:\a\r1\a\DacFramework.msi" /q /le "D:\a\r1\a\DacFramework.log"'
```

git-bash command set

```
echo "change directory to DAC bin"
cd "/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/150/DAC/bin"

echo "print present working directory"
pwd

echo "ls SqlPackage.exe"
ls SqlPackage.exe

echo "sql package version"
./SqlPackage.exe -version
```

output is as below

> 15.0.5164.1