# How to set installation status for wix msi to command prompt

Tags: c#, installation, cmd, wix, windows-installer

I am using wix installer .msi.
When i run it quitly with command "*msiexec.exe /i Installer.msi /QN /L*V "msilog.log"*", it install and creates a log file.

CMD does not hold to wait to complete the installation OR does not show the status of installation.

My question is that
How to hold the CMD while installation is in progress ?
How to show installation status to CMD for wix installer?

Edit : I have tried **start /wait msiexec.exe /i installer.msi  PASSWORD="pass" /QN /L*V "msilog.log"** . It holds the cmd screen until installation process completed. Its fine now.

2nd question, I tried to get the status of the installation after the above command. "**NET HELPMSG %errorLevel%**". It gives the correct status if executed as separate commend.

When excecuted as combined like ***start /wait msiexec.exe /i installer.msi  PASSWORD="pass" /QN /L*V "msilog.log" & NET HELPMSG %errorLevel%*** , its always return 0-Successfully installed even in case of error.

Please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

As [Heath Stewart](https://www.facebook.com/heath.stewart) of Microsoft (Senior Engineer) explains here: [**Waiting for msiexec.exe to Finish**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/waiting-for-msiexec-exe-to-finish/) - you can try the start wait construct exemplified as follows:

```
start /wait msiexec.exe /i Installer.msi /QN /LV "msilog.log"
```

Do visit the above link for technical details. Essentially Widows Installer always returns to the console immediately unless you specifying for it to wait using the above construct.

---

***Links:***

- [Using Powershell to deal with MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434089/microsoft-installer-command-line-string-parameter-not-working/53436779#53436779)

Comment: Adding this /wait , holds the cmd. Any idea of showing status that whether installation failed or pass with wix installer ?

Comment: Will get back later to look, you have `echo %errorlevel%` that you can try after running a command, but I read Raymond Chen's blog on that - and there was an issue with this - https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html - Also: are you in a batch file or just pushing command lines? One of Chen's blog (that I don't have the time to re-read right now: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=20743).

Comment: i m using wix package which combines 2 msi.  It install 2 services. command i uses as "start /wait Installer.Package -q PASSWORD="pass"

Comment: Are you in a Burn bundle??

Comment: Yes. using wix bootstrapper bundle with 2 msi.