# Powershell Throws “Cannot Validate The Argument on Parameter” Error But Still Works?

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

Fairly simple line in my Powershell script to run an install. The line works- the installer comes up and completed successfully. Yet this error persists.

```
Start-Process -Wait (msiexec.exe /I “C:\Temp\MBAM 2.5\Installers\x64\MBAMClient.msi”)
```

The error:

```
Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ‘C:\Temp\MBAM 2.5\Installers\x64\MBAMClient.msi’
At line:1 char:1
```

Even though it works it’s important not to have errors in my console not only for obvious reasons but also for approval.

Comment: Use **straight** quotes, not the curly thingies you get when copying from internet, MS Word, Outlook, etc.

Comment: They’re actually straight quotes, I typed this on my phone real quick as I’m not logged in on this test PC. Thanks though.

Comment: What if you use the Call operator (`&`) as in `& msiexec.exe /I 'C:\Temp\MBAM 2.5\Installers\x64\MBAMClient.msi'` ?. P.S. The error shows an extra leading space in front of the path. Is that also a typo?

Comment: That was a typing error. I’ll try the operator now.

Comment: Same exact issue using &.

Comment: For the record: [there is a Powershell module for MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53436779/129130). I have just tested it briefly, but it is from [Heath Stewart](https://twitter.com/mrhestew) of Microsoft.

Comment: You removed the `Start-Process` right? `& msiexec.exe /I 'C:\Temp\MBAM 2.5\Installers\x64\MBAMClient.msi'` is the whole command

Comment: Or try `Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I "C:\Temp\MBAM 2.5\Installers\x64\MBAMClient.msi"'`

Comment: [Seen this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442842/129130)? (I don't use Powershell much).

Comment: @theo my final solution was simply ‘Start-Process -Wait ‘C:\Path...\’ works flawlessly and it’s simpler. Still no idea why I was getting the original error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by simplifying the command to:

‘Start-Process -Wait ‘C:\Temp\MBAM 2.5\Installers\x64\MBAMClient.msi’‘

That’s all it took. Installs, waits, and no error.